# Media Query Orientation Mobile Responsive Portrait to Landscape

Tags: css

I am having difficulties by this mobile responsive from portrait to landscape view. I am using this code

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
```

but this code is for only iPhone x screen size, and it's not working to some different screen sizes. Is there a way/ codes that can apply for all mobile media sizes? Can you give me a tip, how is the right coding to do the responsive portrait to landscape? or is there a way can disable the mobile landscape?

Comment: What is that you want to match with your media query?

Comment: I like all my mobile view responsive can also view on landscape.

Comment: have a look at this link, hopefully it will help :) 
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_intro.asp